# vagrant now reporting error about nginx user not being created

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, vagrant

This was working fine - cant seem to find out what changed either - but my vagrant up is now reporting this:

Any help appreciated as to why:

Error executing action `create` on resource 'directory[/var/log/nginx]'

================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound

---

cannot determine user id for 'nginx', does the user exist on this system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you don't create nginx user anywhere.

```
user 'nginx' do
  system true
end
```

Comment: AS mentioned it was working fine without this. Added though and got it working thx.